# breqn doesn't break line automatically

Tags: line-breaking, breqn

I have an issue with the `breqn` environment. The following code doesn't break lines automatically, although there are plenty of feasible breakpoints, e.g., `+`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}


\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
(m \delta m ((i k_{y} \beta^{(p)} \zeta_{P} \rho_{c}^{(n)} p_{0}^2)/(2 g_{P} \sigma  p_{0}^6+8 m Q_{0}^3 \beta^{(n)} \sigma  p_{0}^4+g_{P} m Q_{0} \beta^{(p)} p_{0}^2)+(4 i Q_{0} (k_{y} Q_{0}^2 \zeta_{P} {\beta^{(p)}}^2+k_{y} (4 m \beta^{(n)} Q_{0}^3+g_{P} p_{0}^2) (g_{P} \lambda_{Q}-Q_{0} \beta^{(p)} \lambda_{2})) \rho_{c}^{(n)} (\rho_{c}^{(p)} \sigma  p_{0}^4-m \rho +m Q_{0} \beta^{(p)} \rho_{c}^{(p)}+\rho_{c}^{(p)}) p_{0}^2)/((2 g_{P} \sigma  p_{0}^6+8 m Q_{0}^3 \beta^{(n)} \sigma  p_{0}^4+g_{P} m Q_{0} \beta^{(p)} p_{0}^2) (g_{P}^2 m \rho_{c}^{(p)} p_{0}^4+4 m Q_{0}^2 \beta^{(p)} (Q_{0} \rho -g_{P} p_{0}^2 \rho_{c}^{(p)})-4 Q_{0}^3 \beta^{(p)} \rho_{c}^{(p)} (\sigma  p_{0}^4+1)))+(i k_{y} (4 m \beta^{(n)} Q_{0}^3+g_{P} p_{0}^2) (2 Q_{0} \lambda_{Q}-p_{0}^2 \lambda_{2}) \rho_{c}^{(n)})/(Q_{0} (2 g_{P} \sigma  p_{0}^6+8 m Q_{0}^3 \beta^{(n)} \sigma  p_{0}^4+g_{P} m Q_{0} \beta^{(p)} p_{0}^2))))/(4 \rho_{c}^{(n)})
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

The code above gives:
[image: this]

Any alternative way of automatically breaking equations of this type is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the primitive TeX linebreaking with no package at all (breqn is avoiding breaking inside `()`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.7}\selectfont
$\displaystyle
  (m \delta m ((i k_{y} \beta^{(p)} \zeta_{P} \rho_{c}^{(n)}
  p_{0}^2)/(2 g_{P} \sigma p_{0}^6+8 m Q_{0}^3 \beta^{(n)} \sigma
  p_{0}^4+g_{P} m Q_{0} \beta^{(p)} p_{0}^2)+(4 i Q_{0} (k_{y} Q_{0}^2
  \zeta_{P} {\beta^{(p)}}^2+k_{y} (4 m \beta^{(n)} Q_{0}^3+g_{P}
  p_{0}^2) (g_{P} \lambda_{Q}-Q_{0} \beta^{(p)} \lambda_{2}))
  \rho_{c}^{(n)} (\rho_{c}^{(p)} \sigma p_{0}^4-m \rho +m Q_{0}
  \beta^{(p)} \rho_{c}^{(p)}+\rho_{c}^{(p)}) p_{0}^2)/((2 g_{P} \sigma
  p_{0}^6+8 m Q_{0}^3 \beta^{(n)} \sigma p_{0}^4+g_{P} m Q_{0}
  \beta^{(p)} p_{0}^2) (g_{P}^2 m \rho_{c}^{(p)} p_{0}^4+4 m Q_{0}^2
  \beta^{(p)} (Q_{0} \rho -g_{P} p_{0}^2 \rho_{c}^{(p)})-4 Q_{0}^3
  \beta^{(p)} \rho_{c}^{(p)} (\sigma p_{0}^4+1)))+(i k_{y} (4 m
  \beta^{(n)} Q_{0}^3+g_{P} p_{0}^2) (2 Q_{0} \lambda_{Q}-p_{0}^2
  \lambda_{2}) \rho_{c}^{(n)})/(Q_{0} (2 g_{P} \sigma p_{0}^6+8 m
  Q_{0}^3 \beta^{(n)} \sigma p_{0}^4+g_{P} m Q_{0} \beta^{(p)}
  p_{0}^2))))/(4 \rho_{c}^{(n)})$
  
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works indeed, but when it is not inside any environment, it has no automatic numbering. When putting your solution inside the ```equation``` environment the line is not broken automatically.

Comment: @PawełKorzeb put `\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)` somewhere suitable then it will have a number

Comment: It works, but the number appears at the beginning of the equation, not on a side as in the ```equation``` environment

Comment: @PawełKorzeb "somewhere suitable" eg use `\begin{center}\refstepcounter{equation}\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}\centering$...matth stuff$\end{minipage}\hfill(\theequation}\end{center}`

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you! There is still, however a small issue. How to allow the page to break inside such a structure? I have 3 consecutive long equations displayed by 

```\begin{center}
\refstepcounter{equation}\begin{minipage}{.93\textwidth}
$\displaystyle
  math...\allowbreak$
  \end{minipage}\hfill(\theequation)
\end{center}
```
and each of them starts from a new page. I would like them to break between pages. Adding ```\allowbreak``` at the end of math mode doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: the site doesn't really work well if you ask new questiins in comments. a standard `equation` won't break over a page either. by far the simplest way would be to remove the minipage and place the equation number at the top row, something like  `\begin{center}\hspace*{\fill}(\theeequation}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}$....`